# Rewrite bash command to be ShellCheck compliant

Tags: bash, shell, shellcheck

How can I rewrite the following bash command to be [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/) compliant?

```
memory=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'MemTotal:' | awk {'print $2}' 2> /dev/null)
```

It is currently complaining about:

- Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..'
- This { is literal.

Comment: I think you meant 'useless' instead of 'unless' (Consider cut&pasting the errors in future). I've edited it to suit.  Have you considered making those changes that were suggested by the tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shellcheck complaints are

- Using `cat filename | grep 'pattern'` instead of `grep 'pattern' filename`
- The first brace in the awk command is on the outside of the single quote, hence literal; it should be `awk '{command}'`

So, a version that would satisfy shellcheck would look like

```
memory=$(grep 'MemTotal:' /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}')
```

I'm not sure why you redirected standard error, so I dropped it.

However, piping grep output to awk is rarely the best solution; awk can do almost anything grep can, so you could further simplify to

```
memory=$(awk '/MemTotal:/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo)
```

No pipes!

Answer (score 2):

Just as a guess, you probably want:

```
memory=$(grep 'MemTotal:' /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}' 2> /dev/null)
```

However, that's a direct interpretation of the shellcheck output, so I am unsure as to what you are asking about.  As it stands, you are essentially asking: "Why isn't this working?".

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.